# Minimum 3.5 second load time for FirebaseUI's FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We noticed that our RecyclerAdapters take a minimum of 3.5 seconds to load data from our firebase realtime database and display the data. We're trying to figure out what's causing this lag, or if it's an SDK issue. We're using firebase-ui-database:3.1.0 to support API 26 without being yelled at by the compiler.

```
Query query = mEvalRef.orderByChild(IS_DRAFT_KEY).equalTo(true);
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Assessment> options = new 
FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Assessment>()
            .setQuery(query, Assessment.class)
            .build();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.draft_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Assessment, ReusableViewHolder>(options) {
        ReusableViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ReusableViewHolder holder, final int position, Assessment model) {
            Log.d("ViewHolder Info", "ViewHolder Bound");
            holder.companyName.setText(model.getCompany());
            holder.industryName.setText(model.getIndustry());
            holder.locationName.setText(model.getLocation());
            holder.ownerName.setText(model.getOwnerName());
            holder.dateCreated.setText(model.getLocalizedDate());

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ViewDraftsActivity.this, EditDraftActivity.class);
                    String selectedItem = mRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                    intent.putExtra("assessment_key", selectedItem);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_right, R.transition.slide_out_left);
                }
            } );
        }

        @Override
        public ReusableViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Log.d("ViewHolder Info", "ViewHolder Inflated");
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.completed_and_drafts_list_item, parent, false);
            return new ReusableViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DatabaseError e) {
            Snackbar.make(contentView,
                    "There was an error fetching the list of Draft Assessments. " +
                            "Please check your internet connection",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
```

Our data has been flattened and denormalized and is relatively simple to begin with, so we know it's not due to that. Here are the logs:

```
06-11 14:54:24.958 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: Activity Created
06-11 14:54:24.978 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
06-11 14:54:24.984 8165-8270/com.[my_app_sig] D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=QuickCheckHomeActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8222266655409448112, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ViewDraftsActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8222266655409448111}]
06-11 14:54:25.021 1439-1439/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 12587008
06-11 14:54:25.037 1439-1439/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 12587008
06-11 14:54:25.060 1439-1439/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 12587008
06-11 14:54:25.126 8165-8270/com.[my_app_sig] D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 14:54:25.135 8165-8214/com.[my_app_sig] D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fc86080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9fc83da0)
06-11 14:54:25.147 8165-8170/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=249KB, data=141KB
06-11 14:54:25.149 8165-8170/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=247KB, data=103KB
06-11 14:54:25.153 8165-8170/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=248KB, data=111KB
06-11 14:54:25.154 8165-8170/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=248KB, data=111KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
06-11 14:54:25.157 8165-8279/com.p3_[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7045 bytes, free space 120 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.157 1973-1995/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.[my_app_sig]/com.[my_app_sig].ViewDraftsActivity: +234ms
06-11 14:54:25.232 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7045 bytes, free space 1600 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.327 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] I/chatty: uid=10085(u0_a85) FirebaseDatabas identical 3 lines
06-11 14:54:25.348 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7045 bytes, free space 1600 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.372 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7045 bytes, free space 1744 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.398 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7045 bytes, free space 1532 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.422 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7050 bytes, free space 1380 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.451 8165-8279/com.[my_app_sig] W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 14078 bytes, free space 10984 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
06-11 14:54:25.466 1449-1449/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-11 14:54:26.199 2680-8271/com.google.android.gms D/FA-SVC: Updated lifetime engagement user property with value. Value: 69566662
06-11 14:54:26.215 2680-8271/com.google.android.gms D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 1011
06-11 14:54:26.345 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 255572(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 82(1720KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 44MB/50MB, paused 442us total 112.314ms
06-11 14:54:26.582 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 328516(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 103(2MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 53MB/59MB, paused 447us total 103.473ms
06-11 14:54:26.724 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 389527(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 122(2MB) LOS objects, 9% free, 58MB/64MB, paused 475us total 119.474ms
06-11 14:54:26.881 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 411814(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 128(2MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 63MB/69MB, paused 470us total 133.975ms
06-11 14:54:27.054 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 444470(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 136(2MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 71MB/77MB, paused 457us total 149.379ms
06-11 14:54:27.217 8165-8176/com.[my_app_sig] I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 507592(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 156(3MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 76MB/82MB, paused 478us total 140.518ms
06-11 14:54:27.305 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.315 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.322 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.325 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.328 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.332 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.335 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.339 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.342 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.345 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
```

sanitized so you can see the activity creation compared to the ViewHolder inflation:

```
06-11 14:54:24.958 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: Activity Created
06-11 14:54:27.305 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.315 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.322 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.325 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.328 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.332 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.335 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.339 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
06-11 14:54:27.342 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Inflated
06-11 14:54:27.345 8165-8165/com.[my_app_sig] D/ViewHolder Info: ViewHolder Bound
```

Any ideas on improving this performance would be great, and if you need clarification on anything please let me know!

Comment: How many items are you loading at once?

Comment: There are currently like 50 items to display, but most screens only have room for around 5

Comment: I have just tested the load times with various number of items to display:
1 item: 0.3s cache, 1.0s from fresh app start
10 items : 0.3s cache load, 1.2s from fresh app start
35 items : 0.2s cache load, 1.9s from fresh app start

At first i thought it may be a serialization issue from bad data, but after creating a range of new items to verify, I am still having roughly the same load times where they increase linearly

Comment: Same problem @Tadhg Did you get an answer?

Comment: No I have not, just accepted that it is how it is